# Action countdown and confirmation

Tags: wear-os

I'am trying to create a confirmation dialog with a timer just as the one that Android Wear uses. Do I have to create this myself and in that case how do I make the time animation around the "cancel" button?

See link for more information
https://developer.android.com/design/wear/patterns.html#Countdown

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The view you are looking for is called `DelayedConfirmationView`. Please go to the plaform samples and take a look at `DelayedConfirmation` sample, located here: `sdk\samples\android-20\wearable\DelayedConfirmation`

```
<android.support.wearable.view.DelayedConfirmationView
    android:id="@+id/delayed_confirmation"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    app:circle_color="@color/blue"
    app:circle_radius="@dimen/circle_radius"
    app:circle_radius_pressed="@dimen/circle_radius_pressed"
    app:circle_padding="@dimen/circle_padding"
    app:circle_border_width="@dimen/circle_border_normal_width"
    app:circle_border_color="@color/white"/>
```

you will need to set a duration and invoke a start method to initiate the animation:

```
    delayedConfirmationView = (DelayedConfirmationView) findViewById(R.id.delayed_confirmation);
    delayedConfirmationView.setTotalTimeMs(NUM_SECONDS * 1000);
    delayedConfirmationView.setListener(this);
    ...
    delayedConfirmationView.start();
```

Comment: I think this will work with some tweeking. I will accept your answer when I have got it all to work. Looks promising!

Comment: What tweaking do you mean? It is just a circular button with "outer ring" animation, just like that you want to achieve. You can set all colors and sizes via xml attributes + the icon can be set there as well. If you want a text in addition you need to create a `TextView` ane position it appropriate.

Comment: Yes just need to adjust it after my needs. Almost done then I will perform a test.